# Is there a function that gives the size of a pixel (not in meters) of an "ee.Image" in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, geodesic-sphere

I have an ee.Image that I export to TFRecord. I follow this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/tfrecord).
I use this function :

```js
ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
    image = image,
    description = name,
    folder = folder,
    fileNamePrefix = name,
    region = region,
    scale = 30,
    fileFormat = 'TFRecord',
    formatOptions = {
      'patchDimensions': [128,128],
      'kernelSize': [1,1],
      'compressed': True,
    }
  )
```

After classifying my image, I want to convert it to KML. For that, I need the geodesic coordinates of my image's corners.

Normally, I would get them using `ee.image.geometry().bounds()`. However, when converting ee.Image to tfrecord, the patch dimensions (128,128) do not evenly divide the bounding box, so the border tiles along the greatest x/y edges are be dropped. Hence, the coordinates of the 4 corners of my image change (except for the top-left corner).

So, given the coordinates of the top-left corner of my image, and knowing the number of pixels (128,128), I want to recover the coordinates (geodesic) of the four corners.
**How do I get the geodesic size of my pixel ?**

ie :

```js
x2 = x1 + size*128
y2 = y1 + size*128
```

*Note:* I know that my pixel is 30 meters !

Can anyone help? Thanks